# Reversed method does nothing to stack

Tags: java, linked-list, stack, nodes, reverse

This method is supposed to return a copy of the current stack with the items reversed.

```
public LinkedStack<E> reversed()
{
    LinkedStack<E> that= new LinkedStack<E>();
    if(this.isEmpty()==true){
        return this;
    }
    else{
        while(this.isEmpty())//changed from this.isEmpty()==true
            {
            Node<E> snode=this.top;
            that.push(snode.getData());
            this.pop();
            snode=snode.getLink();
                    /*
                      that.push(pop()); works perfectly
                    */

            }
        return that;
        }
    }
```

**Update**
Ok one of the answers seems to bring me closer to the solution. It works but only for the stack created in the method. The problem I'm having is linking it to this stack so that I can return a **copy** of the **`this`** stack. I'm using a linked stack.

Comment: You don't need to use `this.` unless there's a local variable with the same name. And `==true` is unnecessary.

Comment: Returning the original instead of new object in one case (empty) but not the other isn't desirable. What if someone modifies the copy they got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not

```
while(!isEmpty()) {
   revertStack.push(pop());
}
```

At the same time look at your original loop particularly the first line to see what may be causing your problems

Comment: I'm close to solving the problem, I just need a way to set this stack to the that stack

Comment: Which test generates NPE? Did you compare your code with mine and found what your code is doing differently?

Comment: Yes. Thanks, but I have one slight problem. The method is supposed to return a copy of `this` stack reversed. How would I go about returning a reversed copy of this. I've tried setting this to that and returning this but that obviously didn't take me anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: You should always return the result set (`that`).

Comment: Did you rty `LinkedStack<E> revertStack = new LinkedStack<E>(); while(!isEmpty()) {
   revertStack.push(pop());
}
return revertStack;
`

Answer (score 0):

Created three LinkedStacks. Copied first to second, then second  to third then third to first

```
public LinkedStack<E> reversed()
{
    LinkedStack<E> that= new LinkedStack<E>();
    LinkedStack<E> that1= new LinkedStack<E>();
    LinkedStack<E> that2= new LinkedStack<E>();

    if(this.isEmpty()==true){
        return this;
    }
    else{
        while(this.isEmpty())//changed from this.isEmpty()==true
            {
        while(!this.isEmpty()){that.push(this.pop());}
        while(!that.isEmpty()){that1.push(this.pop());}
        while(!that1.isEmpty()){this.push(this.pop());}

            }
        return that;
        }
    }
```